# Не получается нормально сделать кнопку

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Хотелось бы сделать кнопку, да никак не получается.
Вот как этот блок должен выглядеть:
[image: 1]
Пытался использовать `display: flex и inline-flex;`, но когда я его применял к ссылке или вообще к блоку ссылок, они вели себя, как блочные элементы(растягивались на всю ширину, и одна ссылка вставала под другой)

если что, ширина картинок 21px высота - 24px

Еще хотелось бы узнать, почему когда я элементу или блоку задаю`display: flex;`, то ссылка, которая сделана кнопкой, растягивается на всю ширину, хотя, на сколько я знаю, элементу по умолчанию запрещено увеличиваться в размере(такая проблема просто не в первый раз возникает, в прошлый раз я её кое-как решил, задав максимальную ширину, но, как сами понимаете это плохое решение),заранее спасибо!

```css
.download__text_header {
 color: #373737;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.download__text_paragraph {
 color: #373737;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 500;
 letter-spacing: 1.8px;
 line-height: 22px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.download__links_link {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 700;
 letter-spacing: 2.7px;
 background-color: #1abc9c;
 padding: 20px 74px 20px 20px;

}

.download__links_link img {
 background-color: #16A085;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.link1 {
 margin-right: 30px;
}

.download_text {
 text-align: center;
 width: 840px;
 margin: 30px auto 60px;
}

.download__links {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="download">
  <div class="download_text">
   <h2 class="download__text_header">Download it</h2>
   <p class="download__text_paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="download__links">
   <a href="#" class="download__links_link link1">
    <span>Apple store</span>
    <img src="img/icons/apple-icon.svg" alt="img">
   </a>
   <a href="#" class="download__links_link link2">
    <span>Play store</span>
    <img src="img/icons/android-icon.svg" alt="img">
   </a>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не использовал ваш html и css так как посчитал его чуть чуть не верным

1) Делаем кнопки и оборачиваем их в `div`:обычные ссылки за исключением что они в моём случае `inline-block` и внутри span с текстом и иконочный шрифт [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.ru/) и раздавливаем то есть формируем их [внутренними отступами](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/padding) и не используем margin вообще за исключением что бы обнулить их там где это надо или выровнять по центру

2) текст: h3 + p

3) flexbox => `flex-direction: column` который отдельной обёрткой

ps: в section дописано правило padding:30px 0; его удалить это добавленно только для сниппета so

И получаем вот такой результат:
Так как сниппет so чуть чуть отображает ни так то скидываю ссылку на песочницу: [codepen.io/topicstarter](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/XWmmwZe?editors=1100)

```css
* {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

.section {
  background: #fafafa;
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.flex {
  max-width: 690px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.description {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.description h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.definition {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.store {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.store span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.store i {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  background: #16a085;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="section">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="description">
      <h3>download it</h3>
      <p class="definition">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas alias placeat praesentium dicta architecto aperiam quam quos accusantium, tempora enim sint numquam vel eveniet qui quas possimus nulla ut! Incidunt.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="downloads">
      <a href="#" class="store" title="app store">
        <span>apple store</span>
        <i class="fa fa-apple"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="store" title="google play market">
        <span>play store</span>
        <i class="fa fa-android"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```